# AngularJS cannot access directive scope inside controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Directive scope values(initialValue and title) are `undefined` in my controller function - counterController. It prints initialValue if I define it like `{{ counterCtrl.initialValue }}` in `app_counter.directive.html`, but `undefined` in `counterController` function.

**app_counter.directive.js**

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.directive('appCounter', appCounter)
};

function appCounter() {
    let directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: require('./app_counter.directive.html'),
        scope: {
            initialValue: '=',
            title: '@'
        },

        controller: counterController,
        controllerAs: 'counterCtrl',
        bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;
}

function counterController() {
    let vm = this;

    vm.counter = vm.initialValue;
    vm.increment = increment;
    vm.decrement = decrement;

    function increment() {
        vm.counter += 1;
    }

    function decrement() {
        vm.counter -= 1;
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

const angular = require('angular');
const app = angular.module('app', []);

require('./app_counter/app_counter.directive')(app);
```

**app_counter.directive.html**

```
<div class="counter">
    <div>Current value {{counterCtrl.title}}: {{ counterCtrl.counter }}</div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="counterCtrl.decrement()">Decrement</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="counterCtrl.increment()">Increment</button>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<div id="app" ng-app="app">
    <app-counter title="hello" initial-value="10"></app-counter> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access them with `$scope` (as they are) inside your controller instead using your controller instance object (`this`) directly.

```
function counterController($scope) {
    let vm = this;

    vm.counter = $scope.initialValue;
    vm.increment = increment;
    vm.decrement = decrement;

    function increment() {
        vm.counter += 1;
    }

    function decrement() {
        vm.counter -= 1;
    }
}
```

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmo4zs3w/1/)**

---

#### By using **bindToController**:

You can achieve the same by using `bindToController` which is available since AngularJS v1.3:

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      controllerAs: 'counterCtrl',
      bindToController: {
        initialValue: '='
      },
      controller: function () { 
        this.$onInit = function () {

            let vm = this;

            vm.counter = vm.initialValue;
            vm.increment = increment;
            vm.decrement = decrement;

            function increment() {
                vm.counter += 1;
            }

            function decrement() {
                vm.counter -= 1;
            }
        };
      }
    }
});
```

**>> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t14cbsv1/)**

Comment: But I want pass parameters inside the directive and catch them in controller. Is it possible?

Comment: @YevhenRadionov no, but you can use E2E binding or parse/access them as scope param or service/factory.

Comment: Actually, using the `bindToController` option on a directive should bind them to the controller instead of the scope. If you add `bindToController: true` to the directive configuration in the fiddle, you'll see that the `$scope` passed into the controller no longer has a `title` attribute and it is instead on the `this` of the controller. @YevhenRadionov, is that what you want?

Comment: @lin so parameters that I pass as a directive attributes I can use only in directive template, right?

Comment: @lin could you write an example, please. I understood what you mean, but the way I write it, it doesn't work :(

Comment: @james00794 yes, he is able to achieve this in different ways. I added an example of how to do it with `bindToController`. Cheers m8

Comment: @YevhenRadionov yea I could write one. But I need to know where is `increment` / `decrement` defined / set / controlled by?

Comment: I had a look on the example, and you probably did not understand me right.
The question is: can I write in my directive something like this: `<app-counter initial-value="10">` and access this initialValue(I mean 10) from my controller?